# CRTL + Tilde then copy paste "exploded" formulas into excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I would like to view the formulas on my spreadsheet using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>.
Is there a way then to copy paste those "exploded" formulas onto another excel sheet in the "exploded" view?

Comment: I don't think there is a non-VBA way of doing this unfortunately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba.  

However, there are ways of creating a user defined function to get the formula which you could then use i.
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/formula.htm

Comment: If you only need to do it a few times, then just double-click on the cell, select the entire formula, and copy & paste as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of one way, but it requires some outside program. I'm assuming that you have access to notepad or another text editor (I will refer to notepad below, but replace that with other text editors if applicable). The below also applies to a whole sheet.

1. Copy the formula and paste it in notepad. You'll notice the formulae get pasted as you want there.
2. Copy everything again and paste it in the sheet you want it to be, by using Paste Special.
3. Wait! That's not over, because you'll notice excel still evaluate the formula. Click on the little paste icon that appears and select the option "Use text import wizard"
4. Use 'Delimited', Uncheck everything in the next step and in step 3, pick "Text".

Tadaa! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish what you're looking for would be to:

Do a find/replace - Replace all `=` with, say, `#` (or whatever character is specifically NOT in your formulas at all) - so it stops being considered a formula in Excel.

Then copy & paste to the other sheet, then do the opposite find/replace (`#` for `=`).

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: for me this does not work whenever i paste the values get pasted. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no elegant way to do this. The best way I've found is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>, copy the desired range of formulas, then paste them into notepad or another text editing program. Reselect and copy the formulas, which are now just text, and paste them into your new range on the other sheet.