# Reference a cell based on another cell's cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Is there anything that acts like `=CELL("contents",A2)` except returns the formula from `A2` instead of the contents from `A2`?

I want to use a formula from one cell to build a similar formula in another cell.

`A2` currently contains the formula `=Tests!B1`

I want to build a new formula that strips out the `B` and uses another cells data in my Results worksheet to create a new formula that pulls related data from Tests.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to do with input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Excel? 2013+ has FormulaText(...)

https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8

If not, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba) question's answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks Mike.