# Retrieve a cell's formula, not its result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I may have a column of names beside a column of hyperlinks to files related to each name. In another sheet I want to extract the path to the file, NOT the text supplied by the HYPERLINK function. For example:

```
Name    Function
Amy     =HYPERLINK("Users\My Documents\amy000.pdf","Yes")
Bob     =HYPERLINK("Users\My Documents\robert.pdf","Yes")
Charlie =HYPERLINK("Users\My Documents\charli.pdf","No")
Dan     =HYPERLINK("Users\My Documents\daniel.pdf","Yes")
```

What displays in each function cell is "Yes" or "No".

What I want to do is something like

```
MID(Sheet1!B2,13,29)
```

to pull out the text string **Users\My Documents\amy000.pdf** from inside the formula. I want to do this without formatting the original formulas as text.

=CELL("contents",B2) didn't work. Everything I've tried with VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH deal only with the "Yes" or "No" result values, not the original function.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Excel 2013, [FORMULATEXT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) provides what you are looking for.

Otherwise, you could use the workaround from the solution of [Getting formula of another cell in target cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba).

Comment: Thank you. FORMULATEXT worked together with INDEX & MATCH, but didn't work for me with VLOOKUP.