# Excel: Can an address within a cell be used as part of another cell address?

Tags: excel, function, spreadsheet

I keep thinking there must be a function that allows an address within a cell to be used as a variable within another cell address. For the types of sheets I'm creating it would make my life so much easier.

For the purposes of example, the function I seek is hypothetically called "THING" below:

```
Sheet1 Daily Menus

MONDAY MENU
      Items:           Helper Column          Nutritional Data           Results
        A                   B                         C             
1   =Sheet2!A35      =THING(A1,row=35)     =INDIRECT("Sheet3!G"&B1)    =Sheet3!G35
2   =Sheet2!A247     =THING(A2,row=247)    =INDIRECT("Sheet3!G"&B2)    =Sheet3!G247
3   =Sheet2!A989     =THING(A3,row=989)    =INDIRECT("Sheet3!G"&B3)    =Sheet3!G989

TUESDAY MENU
101 =Sheet2!A613     =THING(A101,row=613)  =INDIRECT("Sheet3!G"&B101)    =Sheet3!G613
```

The bottom line is:

In a complex spreadsheet (10 pages, each with hundreds of rows and columns), I want to manipulate the addresses by altering only the data in column A on page 1.

This would also allow me to easily copy column B down for hundreds of rows. The type of function in column B may also be required in columns C, D, E... for dozens or hundreds of columns.

Right now I'm typing in each needed address manually, or a very long function using the address. If anything changes in column A then I have to go back and retype these long functions... and often I find that I've made a typo with all that typing...

Comment: One more problem: is there any other way to extract the row number (instead of using RIGHT)? Because some row numbers are single-digit, double and triple-digit? If not then I will need to insert 99 rows into each sheet being referenced, then hide them. That's my only low-tech solution to getting hundreds of rows with the same number of digits.

Comment: @pnuts I have improved the specificity of my question. You have greatly helped my improve my use of INDIRECT and I am very close to a solution I've sought for years. Thx

Comment: Look at the ROW, COLUMN and ADDRESS functions.

Comment: @Joe ADDRESS isn't working for me, or perhaps I don't understand how to implement it. The ROW function could work if I put an extra row on Sheet2 and have it number itself, then point the INDIRECT toward that...

Comment: @Joe If I use ROW(A1) on Sheet1 then I get "1" ... but I really want it to say "35". Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @pnuts - Admirable formula, but inserting 99 rows and using your RIGHT formula may be faster on a spreadsheet this size.

Comment: BTW I've wondered for about 6 years why Excel doesn't have a quick answer for this type of query. I've encountered this need at least 4 times and have had to create elaborate workarounds for each situation... I can't find anything about this on their Help - you guys have done more for me in the last hour than their lame examples!

Comment: @ Joe If I insert a row on Sheet2 and use ROW(A1) thru ROW(A999) then I get "item numbers" before the items descriptions. Then I make an extra row on Sheet1 that references the "item number" of the "selected item." Then I can use INDIRECT on Sheet1, col B to reference the item name. That begins to work, if each desired item is selected by entering on Sheet1 "=" and "item number" from Sheet2 (not "=" "item description")... I just thought I would be able to select the items on Sheet1 by clicking "=" and "item description" from Sheet2. That's how I've been selecting up to now (more user friendly)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have as your starting point formula `=Sheet2!A35` in cell A1.
What you have to do is:

1. **Get the formula as a string**.
   For this you can use either XL4 macros, VBA, or `FormulaText` (in Excel 2013 or later), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973295/2707864).
2. **Extract the row number from the string**.
   For this you an use VBA ([very easy](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/34245-obtain-row-number-from-a-cell-address)), or a formula to find the rightmost letter/`$` and keep the substring to its right.
3. **Use the previous answer**, as you already incorporated in your question.

---

**Answer to the first version of the question**

I will split the formula you are looking for in two steps.

In cell B1 you can enter `="Sheet2!"&"X"&TEXT(A1,"0")`.
This will produce the result `Sheet2!X25`.
Then in cell C1 you can enter `=INDIRECT(B1)`.
This will bring into cell C1 the contents of cell `Sheet2!X25`.

Notes:

1. You can copy the formula downwards as you need.
2. When copying into other columns, take care of relative/absolute indexing.
3. You could use a single formula (no helper column) in B1: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&"X"&TEXT(A1,"0"))`.
4. Both `Sheet2` and (column) `X` could be replaced by suitable formulas if you want them not be hardcoded.
5. Formula in B1 can almost certainly be replaced by 
   `="Sheet2!"&"X"&A1`.
   NB: A long time time ago, under circumstances I do not recall now, I found I needed to use `TEXT`; YMMV.

Comment: @EverettSteed - If I understand correctly, what you need is something different from what was asked. It seems to me that this answer addresses the question "Can a variable (esp. a cell's contents) be used as part of a cell address?" I suggest you post another question describing what you need, with a specific example (same as you did here, which was great to see the question, and which is often not seen in SO). Readers might be misled otherwise.

Comment: @EverettSteed - If you happen to post another question, you might add a comment here with a link to it, so they becomed tied and readers can follow through.

Comment: I have improved the specificity of my question. I apologize for the confusion, it was only in exploring pnuts suggestions that I became aware of the true complexity of the question, and the heart of the matter. Any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: @EverettSteed - I will try answering the new question. But again, I think you'd better not modified the question, but rather asked a new one, to keep SO useful for others as well.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your message. I understand the logic of leaving questions in their original form, but I was so enthusiastic to ask what I had intended that I totally missed this message. Sorry

Comment: Apparently this problem is common enough that one of you smart programmers should develop a user-friendly function that easily does this desirable task... then sell it to Microsoft.

Comment: @EverettSteed - So did you manage to apply the suggestions for your benefit?