# Is there a formula to look inside another cell's formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am working on is a quality-assurance spreadsheet, designed to analyse and quality check another spreadsheet for any errors in it's output and it's formulas.

On that latter note, I want to know if there's a formula that can inspect a cell (which also contains another formula) and return true or false if it contains a certain string of text, that is PART OF THE FORMULA itself.

**For example,** say in Cell A1 the formula is: `=CEILING.PRECISE(B4)` and equals 3.

I want to find out if the formula contains the word "**Precise**", which would then return **TRUE**. Another example being to see if the formula contains the string "**B4**" which would also return **TRUE**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-target-cell

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what Excel version you use....

**Excel 2013/2016:**

Make use of the build-in `=FORMULATEXT()` [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8). The function will return the formula of the referenced cell as text string. As such you could nest this in an `=IF(...)` statement.

**Lower Excel version:**

Make use of an [UDF](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/function-formulaget.htm) to accomplish the same effect. This doesn't have to be complicated. A simple UDF like below does the job.

```
Function FORMULATEXT(CL As Range)
    FORMULATEXT = CL.Formula
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of JvdV is already giving you everything you need about transforming the formula in a string.

In addition to this you can also use the FIND function to find if the word "PRECISE" is inside your formula.

```
=IF(FIND("PRECISE";FORMULATEXT(A1);1)>0;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

Of course finding if B4 is inside would just be a small change after.